# How to execute method code only once although called every frame

Tags: c++, events, input, triggers, keyboard

I am programming a game and in my InputHandler-class I have written a getKeyState method which returns wether a specific key is being pressed or not (bool).

The problem in some cases is that, no matter how hard I try, pressing a key always takes "so long" that my getKeyState methods return true multiple times, because it is called every frame.

When I need specific actions to only execute once, I have to write something like this:

```
int n = 0; // global variable
```

(...)

```
// --- inside a class method which is called every frame as well: ---

if (Input.getKeyState(key))
{
    n++;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        // specific behaviour
    }
}
else
{
    n = 0;
}
```

My question now is: How can I  achieve this within a method inside my InputHandler class. I don't want to  declare a counter variable every single time, I need a "Key only pressed once"-method. I want to just call:

```
if (Input.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls())
```

Comment: Only once per frame, or once per frame per object?

Comment: Input is a singleton. I didn't write it in here to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
 you need to check for press key and then for unpress key.

```
bool keyPressed = false;

bool InputHandler(){
   if(keyPresed == false){
      if( key is being pressed ){
         keyPressed = true;
         return true;
      }
   }
   else{
      if( key is not being pressed ){
         keyPressed = false;
      }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Edit2:
If you really want InputHandler() do the checking, you can have an array of flags for every caller and give every caller an ID, then if InputHandler() was called, key was pressed and the flag for the ID is false you return true, else you return false, but you have to reset all flags every time key is unpressed.

So the previous code will look something like that:

```
bool arrayReset = true;
bool pressUsed[Number of callers] = {0};

bool InputHandler(int id){
   if(key is being pressed){
      if( pressUsed[id] == false){
         pressUsed[id] = true;
         arrayReset = false;
         return true;
      }
   }
   else if( key is not being pressed && arrayReset == false){
         arrayReset = true;
         set pressUsed[] all elements to false;
   }

return false;
}
```

Edit3:
If you call that method multiple times but in the same loop, you can do the following:

```
bool keyPressed = false;

bool InputHandler(){
   if(key is being pressed && keyPresed == false)
     return true;
}


bool InputHandlerWithChange(){
   if(keyPresed == false){
      if( key is being pressed ){
         keyPressed = true;
         return true;
      }
   }
   else{
      if( key is not being pressed ){
         keyPressed = false;
      }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Call InputHandler() every time you need to check if a key is pressed. Call InputHandlerWithChange() at the end of your loop or at your last place that needs to check for a key press, that way all your callers will receive true when key pressed and will stop receiving true until the key is unpressed.

Comment: That was my first solution too, but the problem is that the InputHandler class is a singleton and when I call that method multiple times from different places in my code only the first one that I call will return true.

Comment: You have to check somehow if the caller is already used this key press. The simplest why will be set a flag for every call (similar to the counter in your example), if getKeyState() returns true and flag is false , do your thing then set flag to true, if getKeyState() returns true and flag is false do nothing, if getKeyState() returns false set flag to false.

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a parent class with a static data member. Then you can create input handlers that inherit from that class.

```
// Main parent class
class InputHandlerParent {
public:
    InputHandlerParent() {} ;
    virtual bool isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls()
    {
        return keypressed;
    }
    virtual void setKeyPressed()
    {
        keypressed = true ;
        std::cout << "YOU PRESSED THE KEY!" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void unsetKeyPressed()
    {
        keypressed = false ;
        std::cout << "YOU RELEASED THE KEY!" << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    static bool keypressed ;
private:
};

// Now an example child class
class InputHandlerChild : public InputHandlerParent {
public:
    InputHandlerChild() :
        InputHandlerParent()
    {};
protected:
private:
};

// Define keypressed
bool InputHandlerParent::keypressed = false ;
```

All of the inheriting child classes share the `keypressed` variable, so if you do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    InputHandlerChild child1 ;
    InputHandlerChild child2 ;

    std::cout << "Child1 pressed: " << child1.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Child2 pressed: " << child2.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;

    // Now set the key as pressed
    child1.setKeyPressed() ;

    std::cout << "Child1 pressed: " << child1.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Child2 pressed: " << child2.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;

    // Unset the key ONLY if it was set for child2
    if (child2.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls()) {
        child2.unsetKeyPressed() ;
    }

    std::cout << "Child1 pressed: " << child1.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Child2 pressed: " << child2.isKeyPressedAndTriggerOnlyOncePls() << std::endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

this gives the output

```
Child1 pressed: 0
Child2 pressed: 0
YOU PRESSED THE KEY!
Child1 pressed: 1
Child2 pressed: 1
YOU RELEASED THE KEY!
Child1 pressed: 0
Child2 pressed: 0
```

so even though i only pressed it for one child, EVERYONE knows it was pressed. Basically, whenever the key is pressed, you can call `setKeyPressed()` to set `keypressed` to true. Then whenever the action happens that un-sets the key you can call `unsetKeyPressed()` to let everyone know the key is no longer pressed.